# Create Spline from Coefficients and Knots in GAMLSS

Tags: splines, gamlss

In the *R* package [GAMLSS](https://www.gamlss.com/), it is possible to model a random variable $Y$ as a smoothed non-parametric function of some predictor $x$.

One option for such a function is the penalised spline using `y~pb(x)`. This outputs a list of coefficients and knots which, combined with a set of [basis splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline), results in a smooth function of $x$.

How can one recreate the spline function, given the coefficients and the knots? (Preferably without having to write my own b-spline generating function).

For example:

```
library(gamlss)
set.seed(9876)
xstart <- 0
xend <- 100
datan <- 20000

seq <- seq(xstart, xend)
mean <- sapply(seq, function(x){0.5+0.2*sin(x/10)})
xs <- ceiling(runif(datan, xstart, xend))
ys <- sapply(xs, function(x){rnorm(1, mean = mean[x], sd = 0.1)})

m1 <- gamlss(ys~pb(xs))
plot(xs, ys)
lines(seq, mean, col="red")
lines(xs[order(xs)], fitted(m1)[order(xs)], col="green")

intercept <- m1$mu.coefficients[1] # 0.5495853
weight <- m1$mu.coefficients[2] # -0.0002851018
coefficients <- c(m1$mu.coefSmo[[1]]$coef) # c(-0.170704842, -0.066451626,  0.026591530,  0.119289203,  0.159657021,  0.149185418,  0.086505094,  0.003904402, -0.100156999, -0.188811997, -0.238717366, -0.237884900, -0.197802945, -0.090559794,  0.012576273,  0.101003289,  0.169210741,  0.181836117,  0.143883546,  0.061281663, -0.038608572, -0.136215586, -0.232871483)
knots <- m1$mu.coefSmo[[1]]$knots # c(-5.039,  0.010,  5.059, 10.108, 15.157, 20.206, 25.255, 30.304, 35.353, 40.402, 45.451, 50.500, 55.549, 60.598, 65.647, 70.696, 75.745, 80.794, 85.843, 90.892, 95.941 100.990 106.039)
```

[image]

How can I obtain the green function, knowing only the intercept, weight, coefficients and knots? I currently plot this function using `fitted(m1)`. However, this is simply a list of $y$ values for the originally inputted list of $x$ values, it is not a function which gives $y$ for any new $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the pb() function fits P-splines as described by Eilers and Marx (1996): B-splines on equally spaced knots and finite difference penalties. In the same paper there are some code chunks that show how to fit the model (in the appendix if I remember well).
I do not know about the details of the fitted.gamlss method but the code below should be helpful (look at the blue line in the plot).

To compute the B-spline bases, I use the function splineDesign from splines package (the same function is used in the reference I menitoned above if I remember well).

To get $\hat{y}$ for a new value of $x$, you can just compute the corresponding value of the splineDesign function and use the coefficeints estimated before (see last line of the code and the green dot)

```
# B-splines stuffs - observed xs
ndx   = 20
deg   = 3
xr    = max(xs)
xl    = min(xs)
xmax  = xr + 0.01 * (xr - xl)
xmin  = xl - 0.01 * (xr - xl)
dt    = (xmax - xmin) / ndx
knots = seq(xmin - deg * dt, xmax + deg * dt, by = dt)
B     = splineDesign(knots = knots, x = xs, ord = deg + 1, derivs = 0,outer.ok = TRUE)

# Compute smooth
ff    = intercept + weight * xs + B %*% coefficients 

# New x-value
xn    = 35
Bn    =  splineDesign(knots = knots, x = xn, ord = deg + 1, derivs = 0,outer.ok = TRUE)
fn    = intercept + weight * xn + Bn %*% coefficients 

# Plot Results
lines(xs[order(xs)], ff[order(xs)], col = 'blue', lty = 2, lwd = 2)
points(xn, fn, col = 'green', pch = 16, cex = 1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gi_F. Why does $xmax = xr + 0.01 * (xr - xl)$ and not $xmax = max(xs)$? Where does the $0.01$ come from?

Comment: The output of Gamlss gives 23 knots, just as there are 23 coefficients. However, the `splineDesign` functions requires 27 knots. For evenly spaces knots, these can easily be obtained from the original 23 using: $$c(head(knots, n=2) - 2 * knots[2] + 2 * knots[1], \\knots, \\tail(knots, n=2) + 2 * knots[2] - 2 * knots[1])$$ However, could you explain why `splineDesign` requires 27?

Comment: 1commemt)The xmax/xmin depends on the way the function pb() Is written in the gamlss package (it is a choice of the package authors)..it is not so important after all. 2comment)The number of knots, depend on the properties of the B-spline functions. In general, the total number of knots needed is ndx + 2*deg+ 1 (see also'value' session of splineDesign() keeping in mind ord = deg + 1). B-splines are presented in a really accessible way in par 2 of Eiles and Marx 1996. Hope this clarifies a bit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function call to generate new $y$ values for any $x$.

```
predict(m1, newdata = data.frame(xs = new_x), data = data.frame(xs=xs))
```

Note that my `xs` is from the `xs` in your example. In general, you'll need to modify this to provide the original data to the `predict` function, with the original names.

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for (or I am misunderstanding it). This recreates the list of $y$ values for the originally inputted list of $x$ values (the `xs` in the code). This is similar to the `fitted(m1)`. It does not seem to be able to give a $y$ for any new $x$.

Comment: Sorry! I'll clarify.

Comment: Actually, my answer was straight-up wrong, so I completely changed it.

Comment: Thanks for changing your answer. It's pretty close to what I expected. Perhaps this is simply the best option available in the GAMLSS package. I had prefered not to need the `m1` model, but only use the `coefficients` and the `knots`. This should be possible *in principle*, but it might not be implemented anywhere.

Comment: It might be worth looking for the source code for the `predict` method if it's open source.

Comment: https://github.com/cran/gamlss/blob/master/R/predict.gamlss.R

Comment: Welp, I can't really read that, but line 233-34 seems promising: `gamlss.pb(data[["pb(Fl)"]], z, w)`.